# How to use C# to search on Tor Browser through marionette?

Tags: c#, tor, firefox-marionette

i have a problem using C# to search on tor.

This is my code:

some question are commented in the code

```
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(geckodriver);
            service.FirefoxBinaryPath = torPath;
            service.BrowserCommunicationPort = 2828;

            //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv\\
            var options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
            options.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
            options.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9153);
            options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
            options.AddArgument("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9153");

            //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-or-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\
                  //(I tried these two options and neither worked(not at the same time obviously))

            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profilePath);
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9153);
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", false);
            var options = new FirefoxOptions
            {
                Profile = null,
                LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Trace
            };
            options.AddArguments("-profile", profilePath);
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\

            FirefoxDriver driver;//(what's the difference between this two?)
            //??IWebDriver driver??\\ (what's the difference between this two?)
            try{driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);}
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Exception");
                //driver.Quit();(I don't know why this command doesn't work here)
                return false;
            }

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://" + link)          

            //Close the browser when finished
            driver.Quit();
```

I hope someone can help me, i can't see where is the error.
In Tor, this is the configuration:

```
    -allowed ports:9153

    -marionette enabled and configured to port 2828
```

The error is: "Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:(random port)/"